# How can I use decltype to get a pointer without a reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, decltype

I have a function:

```
auto get_values_at_indices(auto* array, Vector<int>* indices)
{
    std::vector<decltype(*array)> ret(indices->size());

    for (int i = 0; i < indices->size(); i ++)
    {
        int index = indices[i];
        ret.push_back(array[index]);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I'm calling the function with

```
MyClass** array = new MyClass[100];
std::vector<MyClass*> subset = get_values_at_indices(array, indices);
```

But the compiler sees `decltype(*array)` as `MyClass*&` (as opposed to `MyClass*`, which is what I want) - what should I try?

(PS, I tried `std::vector<decltype(&(***array))> ret(indices->size());` but no dice ;)

Comment: `MyClass** array = new MyClass[100];` — This does not make sense. Either do `MyClass* array = new MyClass[100];` or `MyClass** array = new MyClass*[100];`. At best, just use a _vector-of-vectors_.

Comment: What do you mean by "no dice"? It doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, new MyClass*[100].
And yes "no dice" means didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*array` is an lvalue expression, then [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) yields `T&`, i.e. `MyClass*&`.

> b) if the value category of *expression* is *lvalue*, then `decltype` yields `T&`;

You can perform [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) (or [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) depending on your intent) on the type, e.g.

```
std::vector<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*array)>> ret(indices->size());
```

BTW: `decltype(&(**array))` should work, you're giving one more `*`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure your type can only be an arithmetic or pointer type, you can use unary `operator+`:

```
std::vector<decltype(+*array)> ret(indices->size());
```

It is as if you try to do arithmetic on the *value* - the result cannot be a reference, but is always the type itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not direct answering your question. But I find using `auto` in this place is not quite expressive and it just forces using the clumsy syntax as `remove_reference<decltype(auto>>`.

If you just use the normal template parameter, you can express your intent more easily (and is better supported by the compilers):

```
template <typename T>
auto get_values_at_indices(const T* array, const Vector<int>* indices)
{
    std::vector<T> ret(indices->size());

    for (int i = 0; i < indices->size(); i ++)
    {
        int index = indices[i];
        ret.push_back(array[index]);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Would also change those `Vector<int>*` to `Vector<int>&` and instead of using raw `array T* array`, I would look for using `const span<T>& array` (if you have C++20 compliant compiler, otherwise boost or [GSL](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines).

Comment: Thanks.  I've never come accross span before - I'll look it up.